# Rails first_or_initialize but with conditions

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, orm

I have a User model with email, name, & code fields.
The email must be unique.
Is there a method in rails where I can do this in one shot:

create the user with specific email & code if the email isnt taken yet
or update the code of the user with that email but the name must be equal to 'abc'

or is this the only way?

```
begin
  user.create!(code: ..., email:...)
rescue ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid => e
  if it is email taken error
    User.where(name: 'abc').update(code:...)
  end
end
```

thanks

Comment: you are probably looking for User.find_or_initialize_by(email: 'email'). I don't understand fully what you are after ... if email has to be unique .. .why is their a secondary constraint that the name must be equal to 'abc' ... what are you going to do in the scenario where the email has been taken but is assigned to some other name?

Comment: @David in the scenario where email has been taken but is assigned to some other name, i shouldnt update the code because by right they shouldnt request it

Comment: ah I see ... then probably best to use as I suggest then test on the name for the retrieved record.

Answer (score 0):

Think this is what might be looking for

```
user = User.find_by(email: ...) || User.new(email: ...)
user.assign_attributes(code: ...) if user.name == 'abc' || user.new_record?
user.save if user.changed?
```

Comment: `user.changed?` might not work as intended if you have Json columns in your model

Answer (score 0):

What you want is `#find_or_create_by` with a block:

```
User.find_or_create_by(email: ....) do |user|
  user.code = ... if user.name == 'abc'
end
```

If it finds a user with the given email, the block does not get called.

If it does not find the user with the given email, it will call the block which will update the code only under the condition that the name is 'abc'